# How to enable new notebook editor in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Looking at a jupyter notebook in VS Code at the moment I see this banner at the top of the screen.
[bannerscreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEPSD.jpg)
It reads
"This editor is deprecated and we'll remove it after 1.59 of VS Code. [Learn more about our new notebook editor.](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/08/05/notebooks)"
The link explains that the new notebook editor feature has been disabled and made opt-in rather than forcing on all users. However no instructions are given on how to opt-in and use the new editor.
I'd like to start using the new notebook editor, how to I switch it on?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to switch to the new editor by [right clicking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK3Yv.png) on an `.ipynb` file and selecting *"Open With..."*.

You should then be able select the option "*Configure default editor for '*.ipynb'..."* from the [drop down selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnQ6Z.png) in command palette.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, that seems on the right track but when I do that I only get 2 options, the built in text editor or the old notebook editor:
Text Editor _Built-in_ 
Jupyter Notebook (custom) _Active and Default_
It seems like I might have to install another extension or something to make the new editor available.

Comment: @StevieJski sorry that didn't work for you. What version of VS Code are you using? It looks like my current version is 1.59.1.

Comment: Well this problem has been resolved in latest version of VS Code. It just upgraded me automatically. I'm now on

Answer (score 1):

If you right click the notebook in the explorer panel like @Ben B says, you should have an option in the menu at the bottom that says "Open in Notebook Editor"

Answer (score 0):

Well this problem has been resolved in latest version of VS Code. It just upgraded me automatically. I'm now on Version: 1.60.1
@SO folks, what is the protocol here? I'd like to give @Ben some credit for helping here but really the answer here is now "upgrade to latest version VS Code"

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29940437)